# Можно ли создать аналогию в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата

В общем я только начал изучать программирование, и решил написать программу которая считает сколько дней осталось до конца года, месяца, но столкнулся с проблемой, " Как высчитать високосный год?"
То есть, високосный год идет через каждые четыре года, 2004, 2008, 2012 и т. д. И вот как написать вот это "и т.д."?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В текущей формулировке непонятно, в чём конкретная проблема у вас и что конкретно вы хотите получить. Если вам нужно число дней до нового года, то это делается в одну строчку `days = (datetime.datetime(datetime.datetime.now().year + 1, 1, 1, 0) - datetime.datetime.now()).days` — и не надо никакие високосные года считать, питон сам разберётся

Comment: Я говорю не конкретно о этой программе, а о том как в принципе делать подобные продолжения. Приведу ещё примеры. 20, 22, 24, 26 и так далее, но придется написать очень много строчек кода, что бы вместить все числа. Я спросил можно ли написать это как то кратко

Comment: Время у нас бесконечное и годы тоже бесконечные, вы никуда не сможете вместить бесконечность. Зачем вам это понадобилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно проверять остаток от деления.

```
(year % 4) == 0
```

Данное условие будет True для каждого года `year`, кратного 4

Но тут нужно учитывать, что на самом деле правило, определяющее високосность года, не такое простое. Например, года кратные 100, но не кратные 400, високосными не считаются.

Полное правило на питоне записывается так:

```
(year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен цикл -  **for**, если вы знаете, когда закончить, или **while**, если решение об остановке нужно будет принять по какому-то условию.

```
for year in range(2004, 2081, 4):
    ...
```

Однако помните, что определение високосного года на длинный период посложнее, чем "каждый четвертый"